# Attribute Error for "from brightway2 import *"

Tags: import, attributeerror, brightway

when I try to import brightway2 into jupyter-lab I get attribute error and I have tried several ways but the problem continues. So I need help.
to open jupyter-lab I follow this steps - from the anaconda -> environment -> brightway -> open with terminal.
then, I open the jupyter-lab with the terminal.
then, I am trying to import brightway to the jupyter-lab by the command `from brightway2 import *` gives me the following attribute error below. Also when I try to do this directly through the terminal from anaconda I get the same error. I also tried different versions of numpy but didn't work. My brightway and everything else is updated.
**My computer: ** MacBook Pro 2017 - 2.3 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5 , Intel Iris Plus Graphics 640 1536 MB , 16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3 , macOS 13.6.1 (22G313)
has anyone else had this problem, how did you solve it, is there a method you recommend? how can I solve this?

**The error:**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 from brightway2 import *

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bw/lib/python3.11/site-packages/brightway2/__init__.py:2
      1 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*
----> 2 from bw2data import *
      3 from bw2calc import *
      4 from bw2io import *

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bw/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bw2data/__init__.py:64
     61 config.p = preferences
     63 from .serialization import JsonWrapper
---> 64 from .database import DatabaseChooser as Database, get_activity
     65 from .data_store import DataStore, ProcessedDataStore
     66 from .method import Method

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bw/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bw2data/database.py:6
      3 from eight import *
      5 from . import databases, config
----> 6 from .backends.single_file import SingleFileDatabase
      7 from .backends.json import JSONDatabase
      8 from .backends.peewee import SQLiteBackend

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bw/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bw2data/backends/__init__.py:5
      2 from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals
      3 from eight import *
----> 5 from .base import LCIBackend
      6 from .peewee import SQLiteBackend
      7 from .json import JSONDatabase

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bw/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bw2data/backends/base.py:12
      3 from eight import *
      5 from .. import (
      6     config,
      7     databases,
   (...)
     10     projects,
     11 )
---> 12 from ..data_store import ProcessedDataStore
     13 from ..errors import UntypedExchange, InvalidExchange, UnknownObject
     14 from ..query import Query

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bw/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bw2data/data_store.py:151
    147         self.validator(data)
    148         return True
--> 151 class ProcessedDataStore(DataStore):
    152     """
    153 Brightway2 data stores that can be processed to NumPy arrays. In addition to ``metadata`` and (optionally) ``validator``, subclasses should define:
    154 
   (...)
    160 
    161     """
    162     dtype_fields = None

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bw/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bw2data/data_store.py:172, in ProcessedDataStore()
    162 dtype_fields = None
    163 # Numpy columns names can't be unicode
    164 base_uncertainty_fields = [
    165     (numpy_string('uncertainty_type'), np.uint8),
    166     (numpy_string('amount'), np.float32),
    167     (numpy_string('loc'), np.float32),
    168     (numpy_string('scale'), np.float32),
    169     (numpy_string('shape'), np.float32),
    170     (numpy_string('minimum'), np.float32),
    171     (numpy_string('maximum'), np.float32),
--> 172     (numpy_string('negative'), np.bool),
    173 ]
    175 @property
    176 def dtype(self):
    177     """Returns both the generic ``base_uncertainty_fields`` plus class-specific ``dtype_fields``. ``dtype`` determines the columns of the :ref:`processed array <processing-data>`."""

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bw/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py:324, in __getattr__(attr)
    319     warnings.warn(
    320         f"In the future `np.{attr}` will be defined as the "
    321         "corresponding NumPy scalar.", FutureWarning, stacklevel=2)
    323 if attr in __former_attrs__:
--> 324     raise AttributeError(__former_attrs__[attr])
    326 if attr == 'testing':
    327     import numpy.testing as testing

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool'.
`np.bool` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `bool`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.bool_` here.
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
```

- Also when I try to do this from anaconda directly through the terminal I get the same error.
- I tried to update everything dumpy, brightway.
- I also created another environment on anaconda for brightway and opened the jupyter-lab again and got the same error for `from brightway2 import *` command.
- I tried different versions of numpy like 1.19.0 and 1.20.0 but didn't work.

Comment: You seem to have conflicting versions of dependent packages. There is a working JupyterLite session offered [here](https://docs.brightway.dev/projects/live/). You can maybe check the version there and try to match up the versions in your environment. Make sure you activated the environment you are trying to work in and install the specific versions in that. You can use [the magic install commands](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) to try and install to the proper environment from inside your running `.ipynb` file.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in [commit 0509092](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-data/commit/05090928eef19b0029af6ef6933622d07e549405) and released in 3.6.6 on Februray 24, 2023.

On conda you can upgrade using:

```bash
conda update bw2data"=3.6.6"
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, Chris' solution worked for me, but in my case, I had to do:

```
conda install -c conda-forge bw2data=3.6.6
```

Hope this helps